# Mongo PHP - Find $criteria w/ $regex Timing Out

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm doing a MongoDB find() on my data set. My data set has over a million documents in total with indexes on as many keys as possible. I've been assured that the collection itself is as optimized as possible.

My app lets you run advanced searches on the collection. I just managed to get a new feature working which lets you run a general "must not contain" filter on top of your already complex search filters. The problem is that the searches are now exceeding Mongo's 30-second limit! Without the general "must not contain" filter, my example search takes around 5 seconds. If I lessen the keys involved, the search comes back in time.

**The goal** of the search is to return documents that don't include "ARSB" in any of the keys specified (there are always a ton of other irrelevant keys in each document). The reason I couldn't simply just run the `$regex` on each key is that the search doesn't return documents that lack any one of the keys if you do that.

The app runs a `find()` query in a PHP script. Here's the slow search `$criteria`:

```
{
  "$and": [
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "columnOne": {
            "$regex": "^((?!ARSB).)*$",
            "$options": "-i"
          }
        },
        {
          "columnOne": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "secondColumn": {
            "$regex": "^((?!ARSB).)*$",
            "$options": "-i"
          }
        },
        {
          "secondColumn": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "finalColumn": {
            "$regex": "^((?!ARSB).)*$",
            "$options": "-i"
          }
        },
        {
          "finalColumn": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "columnOne": {
            "$exists": true
          }
        },
        {
          "secondColumn": {
            "$exists": true
          }
        },
        {
          "finalColumn": {
            "$exists": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What is it that's making this search so slow? Is there any way around it?